# on session end event

Tags: php, session, symfony

I have a Symfony2 project, where at the beginning of each session, I create a folder on the server where the user can manipulate and place his files.

I want to be able to delete the user's folder, when he closes his browser
(or any other related event, maybe check for a session timeout?).

How can I achieve this?

PS: I have read somewhere that java has a sessionHandler where you can code your function.

Is there anything similar in php (Symfony2 specifically)?

Answer (score 4):

First of all, you cannot recongnize if a browser is closed by HTML and PHP. You would need ajax and constant polling or some kind of thing to know the browser is still there. Possible, but a bt complicated, mainly because you might run into troubles if a browser is still there (session is valid) but has no internet connection for a few minutes (laptop, crappy wlan, whatever).

You cannot have a sessionHandler which does this for you in PHP because PHP is executed when a script is retrieved from your server. After the last line is executed, it stops. If no one ever retrieves the script again, how should it do something? There is no magic that restarts the script to check if the session is still there.

So, what to do? First of all you want to make the session visible by using database session storage or something like that. Then you need a cronjob starting a script, looking up all sessions and deciding which one is invalid by now and then does something with it (like deleting the folder). Symfony can help as it allows you to configure session management in a way that it stores sessions in the database (see [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/configuration/pdo_session_storage.html)) as well as creating a task which can be executed via crontab (see [here](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/components/console.html)).

The logical part, which contains deciding which session is invalid and what to do with this sessions) is your part. But it shouldn't be very hard as you got the session time and value in the database.